# Cómo asignar a una variable de tipo control un textbox del formulario en asp.net, c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Este código me sirve para .net forms, pero no para asp.net

```
   string name = "button1";
   Control ctn = this.Controls[name];
   ctn.Text = "ffff";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que se refiere a un WebForm ASP.NET

**ASPX**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server"  />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string name = "button1";
            Control b =this.FindControl(name);
            if (b.GetType().ToString()== "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button")
            {
                ((Button)b).Text = "ffff";
            }
        }
    }
}
```